# Drag and drop issue in Qt

Tags: qt, drag

I overload dragEnterEvent() and dropEvent() in my MainWindow class, and call setAcceptDrops() in the constructor. While the running, I drag a .txt file in to the texteditor, but it's not showing the content of that .txt. Instead, it's show the path of that .txt. Please somebody help where I did wrong. Thanks.

```
//Header
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
protected:
    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event);
    void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

> Blockquote

```
//Source
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDragEnterEvent>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QMimeData>
#include <QList>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setAcceptDrops(true);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event){
    if(event->mimeData()->hasUrls())
        event->acceptProposedAction();
    else event->ignore();
}

void MainWindow::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event){
    const QMimeData *mimeData = event->mimeData();
    if(mimeData->hasUrls()){
        QList<QUrl> urlList = mimeData->urls();
        QString fileName = urlList.at(0).toLocalFile();
        if(! fileName.isEmpty()){
            QFile file(fileName);
            if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))return;
            QTextStream in(&file);
            ui->textEdit->setText(in.readAll());
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Terminology: you *override* the methods. Overloading means a different thing (same function name with different arguments, not related to OOP).

Comment: Thanks to point this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You see this behavior because dropping is enabled on QTextEdit and the event is consumed there. (By default TextEdit drop copies filename into text area.)
In your constructor disable dropping on TextEdit by using

```
ui->textEdit->setAcceptDrops(false)
```

and then the event will be handled by the dropEvent method in MainWindow

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work. the text Editor now is showing nothing.

Comment: Strange...I haven't changed anything in your code, except for adding this line at the end of the MainWindow constructor and it works just fine...Are you sure your constructor ends like this ? '{setAcceptDrops(true); ui->textEdit->setAcceptedDrops(false)}'